# Android sqlite update row nullpointexception

Tags: android, database, sqlite, baseadapter

i working sqlite.i cusscessfully create database,i can insert some values and show it in listview,with baseadapter.now i want to create  update sql function. i wrote some function but i have nullpointexception
this is a my source

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "lvstone_5";
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "CardTable1";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_Tittle = "name";
private static final String KEY_Description = "description";
private static final String KEY_Price = "price";
private static final String KEY_Counter = "counter";
private static final String KEY_Image = "image";
private final ArrayList<Contact> contact_list = new ArrayList<Contact>();
public static SQLiteDatabase db;
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_Tittle + " TEXT,"

            + KEY_Description + " TEXT,"

            + KEY_Price + " TEXT,"

            + KEY_Counter + " TEXT,"

            + KEY_Image + " TEXT"

            + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
    onCreate(db);
}
// Adding new contact
public void Add_Contact(Contact contact) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    if (!somethingExists(contact.getTitle())) {

        values.put(KEY_Tittle, contact.getTitle()); 
        values.put(KEY_Description, contact.getDescription());                                                              
        values.put(KEY_Price, contact.getPrice()); 

        values.put(KEY_Counter, contact.getCounter()); 
        values.put(KEY_Image, contact.getImage());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);

        Log.e("Table Result isss", String.valueOf(values));
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }

}

public void deleteUser(String userName) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, "name = ?", new String[] { userName });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}

public long updateNote(String Counter) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_Counter, Counter);

    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, "counter=" + Counter, null);

}

// Getting single contact
Contact Get_Contact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS,
            new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_Tittle, KEY_Description, KEY_Price,
                    KEY_Counter, KEY_Image }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1),
            cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
    // return contact
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return contact;
}

public boolean somethingExists(String x) {
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_CONTACTS
            + " where name like '%" + x + "%'", null);
    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);

    Log.e("Databaseeeeeeeee", String.valueOf(cursor));
    cursor.close();
    return exists;
}

public ArrayList<Contact> Get_Contacts() {
    try {
        contact_list.clear();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();

                contact.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));

                contact.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));

                contact.setPrice(cursor.getString(3));
                contact.setCounter(cursor.getString(4));

                contact.setImage(cursor.getString(5));

                contact_list.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return contact_list;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("all_contact", "" + e);
    }

    return contact_list;
}
```

}

BaseAdapter.java code

```
public class StradaSQLAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Activity activity;
int layoutResourceId;
Contact user;
ArrayList<Contact> data = new ArrayList<Contact>();
public ImageLoader imageLoader;
UserHolder holder = null;
public int itemSelected = 0;

public StradaSQLAdapter(Activity act, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<Contact> data) {

    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.activity = act;
    this.data = data;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(act.getApplicationContext());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        holder = new UserHolder();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder.Title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.smalltitle1);
        holder.counter = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.smallCounter1);

        holder.dbcounter = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.DBSliderCounter);

        holder.Description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.smallDesc1);

        holder.layout = (RelativeLayout) row
                .findViewById(R.id.DBSlideLayout);
        holder.layoutmain = (RelativeLayout) row
                .findViewById(R.id.DBSlideLayoutMain);
        holder.Price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.smallPrice1);
        holder.pt = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.smallthumb1);
        holder.close = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.DBSliderClose);

        holder.c_minus = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.counter_minus);

        holder.c_plus = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.counter_plus);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    user = data.get(position);

    holder.Title.setText(user.getTitle());
    holder.Description.setText(user.getDescription());
    holder.Price.setText(user.getPrice() + " GEL");

    holder.counter.setText(user.getCounter());

    holder.dbcounter.setText(user.getCounter());

    Log.e("image Url is........", data.get(position).toString());
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(user.getImage(), holder.pt);

    return row;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

public void removeObject(int position) {

    this.data.remove(position);

}
```

}
and Mainjava code

```
public class StradaChartFragments extends Fragment {

public static ListView list;

ArrayList<Contact> contact_data = new ArrayList<Contact>();
StradaSQLAdapter cAdapter;
private DatabaseHandler dbHelper;









private ArrayList<Contact> contact_array_from_db;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.strada_chart_fragment,
            container, false);

    dbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());

    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chart_listview);

    cAdapter = new StradaSQLAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.listview_row_db, contact_data);
    contact_array_from_db = dbHelper.Get_Contacts();


    Set_Referash_Data();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            UserHolder holder = (UserHolder) view.getTag();



            dbHelper.updateNote("3");

        }

    });

    return rootView;
}

public void Set_Referash_Data() {

    for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

        String title = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getTitle();
        String Description = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getDescription();
        String Price = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getPrice();

        String Counter = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getCounter();

        String image = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getImage();

        Contact cnt = new Contact();

        cnt.setTitle(title);

        cnt.setDescription(Description);
        cnt.setPrice(Price);

        cnt.setCounter(Counter);

        cnt.setImage(image);



        contact_data.add(cnt);
    }
    dbHelper.close();

    list.setAdapter(cAdapter);

    Log.e("Adapter issss ...", String.valueOf(cAdapter));
}
```

}
 i have nullpointexception in this function updateNote.
how i can write code witch would can update only Counter value in database and  listview  automaticly refreshed ?
if anyone knows solution help me

Comment: Can you post the exception you're getting ? The logcat output.

Comment: You are calling a method on a object variable which is null at run time.

Comment: i am new user and i can not upload image in stackoverflow  :( this is a  logcat output  error http://postimg.org/image/yg8e3nii7/

Comment: @MrSuS what is a solution. how i can  update only counter value in database ? and also  how i can  refresh listview

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `db` when you call the method `updateNote`.

Add this line `db = this.getWritableDatabase();` at the start of the method `updateNote` and call `db.close()` after updating.

Comment: look. i would  update counter value in my table.only counter value.please see my DatabaseHandler java code again

Comment: After updating you will need to get all the contacts again from the database and set in the listview

Comment: call Set_Referash_Data function after update? i tryed it but nothink changed

Comment: The size of your listview wasn't increased?

Comment: yes if i save new value listview  automaticly  changed

Comment: Then what else do you want?